# Linux, Ubuntu - Very high load but not using cpu/ram

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, debian

I've been using my website for more than half year and this happened to me yesterday for some reason.

My load average is:

Here's some information:

```html
top - 00:37:49 up 15:22,  2 users,  load average: 148.64, 214.47, 218.08
Tasks: 2182 total,   1 running, 2173 sleeping,   8 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.1 us,  1.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 40.7 id, 49.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.5 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  24683624 total,  5226664 used, 19456960 free,   219148 buffers
KiB Swap:  2097084 total,        0 used,  2097084 free,   989136 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  334 root      20   0     0    0    0 D   0.0  0.0   0:19.06 jbd2/md2-8
 8413 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.25 php
 8516 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.25 php
 8540 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.18 php
 8542 root      20   0  245m  12m 7900 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.07 php
 8564 root      20   0  244m  12m 7724 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.22 php
 8624 root      20   0  244m  12m 7724 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.21 php
 9081 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.20 php
 9144 root      20   0  245m  12m 7908 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.07 php
 9145 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.17 php
 9414 root      20   0  245m  12m 7896 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
 9442 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.16 php
 9456 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.18 php
 9481 root      20   0  245m  12m 7896 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.06 php
 9565 root      20   0  245m  12m 7908 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.06 php
 9566 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.20 php
 9735 root      20   0  245m  12m 7900 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.06 php
 9766 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.20 php
 9798 root      20   0  244m  12m 7696 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.20 php
 9827 root      20   0  245m  12m 7916 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.07 php
 9848 root      20   0  244m  12m 7696 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.17 php
 9930 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.15 php
 9999 root      20   0  245m  12m 7900 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.08 php
10004 root      20   0  244m  12m 7696 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.17 php
10008 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.15 php
10022 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.20 php
10150 root      20   0  245m  12m 7912 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
10211 root      20   0  245m  12m 7904 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
10286 root      20   0  245m  12m 7896 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
10297 root      20   0  245m  12m 7896 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
10364 root      20   0  245m  12m 7908 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
10369 root      20   0  245m  13m 7900 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
10389 root      20   0  245m  12m 7896 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
10430 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
10431 root      20   0  244m  12m 7744 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
10435 root      20   0  245m  12m 7896 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
10446 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
10499 root      20   0  244m  12m 7892 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
10597 root      20   0  244m  12m 7740 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
10648 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
10685 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
10730 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.09 php
10749 root      20   0  244m  12m 7744 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
10761 root      20   0  245m  12m 7908 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
10790 root      20   0  244m  12m 7744 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
10797 root      20   0  244m  12m 7736 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
10801 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
10911 root      20   0  244m  12m 7744 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
11023 root      20   0  245m  12m 7904 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
11024 root      20   0  245m  12m 7900 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
11100 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
11146 root      20   0  245m  12m 7900 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
11151 root      20   0  244m  12m 7744 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
11224 root      20   0  244m  12m 7744 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
11255 root      20   0  245m  12m 7908 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
11302 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
11316 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.10 php
11374 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
11475 root      20   0  245m  12m 8016 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
11482 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
11511 root      20   0  245m  12m 7904 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
11605 root      20   0  244m  12m 7740 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
11702 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
11832 root      20   0  245m  12m 7912 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
11835 www-data  20   0  242m  12m 7752 D   0.0  0.1   0:10.03 php
11838 www-data  20   0  242m  12m 7752 D   0.0  0.1   0:10.01 php
11889 root      20   0  245m  12m 7900 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
11920 root      20   0  244m  12m 7704 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.10 php
11939 root      20   0  244m  12m 7700 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.09 php
11951 root      20   0  245m  12m 7900 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
11971 root      20   0  244m  12m 7696 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.10 php
12002 root      20   0  244m  12m 7696 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.09 php
12060 root      20   0  245m  12m 7896 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 php
12068 root      20   0  244m  12m 7744 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 php
12071 root      20   0  244m  12m 7696 D   0.0  0.1   0:00.11 php
12127 root      20   0 21664 1380  180 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
Total status D (I/O wait probably): 76
```

I don't really know what the problem is, sometimes the load average may raise up to 300-500. MySQL also crashed 2 times.

This never happened to me before, could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a runaway sql query or php is thrashing the disk.  Check the slow query log: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html

Turn debugging on for Apache and tail the logs.

Load averages compute not only cpu/ram but network and disk IO as well.  You could have 1% cpu/ram while your disk is thrashing away creating a high load average.